# On implications of Schrodingers Cat regarding macroscopic quantum states and decoherence

Tags: quantum-mechanics, decoherence, schroedingers-cat

How exactly did Schrodingers Cat lead to development regarding macroscopic quantum states and decoherence? One often hears that the thought experiment was the initiator to the question, whether quantum mechanics also applies to the macroscopic world - but so far I couldn't find any reliable sources that state this.

Comment: May be a better fit for [hsm.se]

Comment: In this answer I try to clear up the quantum mechanical from the classical in the famous thought experiment https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/266606/extension-of-schr%c3%b6dingers-cat-thought-experiment/266617#266617